# Mutate based on conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),ind = c("O","O","C","C","O","O","O","O"), num = c(6,12,18,24,6,12,18,24))
set.seed(1)
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]


df2 <- df %>% group_by(x1) %>%
  arrange(x1,num) 
> df2
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   x1 [2]
  x1    ind     num
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 a     O         6
2 a     O        12
3 a     C        18
4 a     C        24
5 b     O         6
6 b     O        12
7 b     O        18
8 b     O        24
```

I want to create some new columns to this data, the first one should check for each unique value of the column `x1` it should take the minimum value of the column `num` where the column `ind` is equal to `C`. For the value `a` this should return `18`. It then does this again but check when `ind` is equal to `O` instead. If it finds nothing then it should just return N/A. So the two columns should be result like this:

```
  x1    ind     num min_O min_C
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     O         6     6    18
2 a     O        12     6    18
3 a     C        18     6    18
4 a     C        24     6    18
5 b     O         6     6    NA
6 b     O        12     6    NA
7 b     O        18     6    NA
8 b     O        24     6    NA
```

I've tried a variation of grouping by the `x1` and `ind` column but couldn't get it to work as I want to do a minimum if it equals a particular value. I am sure there is an easy way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a bit cumbersome but does the job

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
 group_by(x1, ind) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = num, values_fn = min, names_prefix = 'min_') %>% 
 left_join(df2, by = 'x1')

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   x1 [2]
  x1    min_O min_C ind     num
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 a         6    18 O         6
2 a         6    18 O        12
3 a         6    18 C        18
4 a         6    18 C        24
5 b         6    NA O         6
6 b         6    NA O        12
7 b         6    NA O        18
8 b         6    NA O        24
```

Comment: thank you, shall take a look. Was hoping it would be a simple solution I was missing that can do it. Is there no minif function or something in R (as excel)?

Comment: In any case you will have to convert it to wide format though

Comment: Why would that be the case?

Comment: Because you need to generalize it to take way more than just two `ind`. If you don't convert to wide format then you have to do them by hand (see the other answer) so it will be extremely hard and time consuming to scale up

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(x1,num) %>% 
  group_by(x1) %>%
  mutate(min_C = min(num[ind == "C"]), 
         min_O = min(num[ind == "O"]),
         across(starts_with("min"), ~ ifelse(.x == Inf, NA_real_, .x)))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   x1 [2]
  x1    ind     num min_C min_O
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     O         6    18     6
2 a     O        12    18     6
3 a     C        18    18     6
4 a     C        24    18     6
5 b     O         6    NA     6
6 b     O        12    NA     6
7 b     O        18    NA     6
8 b     O        24    NA     6
```

but also returns a warning, since there are no `C` in group `b`.

If you don't use the `across(...)` part, `NA`s are replaced with `Inf`.